# How to set the color of the icon in mudblazor or add more colors to the enum Color?

Tags: mudblazor

```
<MudNavLink Href="/saasform"  Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.InsertDriveFile">Risk Summary Accepted</MudNavLink>
```

I want to change the color of the displayed icon and I can do it by adding IconColor="Color.Primary" and the code looks like

```
 <MudNavLink Href="/saasform" IconColor="Color.Primary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.InsertDriveFile">Risk Summary Accepted</MudNavLink>
```

But we are restricted to use only few colors like Color.Primary, Color.Secondary, Color.Dark etc.,
How do we set the color of the icon as desired ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't set an arbitrary color, only those defined in the `Color` enum. Note that those colors can be changed by changing [the theme](https://mudblazor.com/customization/overview#theme-provider).

Note that there is a feature request to add arbitrary colors: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/470

Comment: I just realized and that's some BS on their part, it should not support only an enum with the values decided by the library developers, we should be able to make our own enum of colors with the names we want, without having to resort to CSS

Comment: @Sasino I updated my answer with a link to a feature request for providing arbitrary colors: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/470